# Pulling Data Between Excel Worksheets

Tags: sql, excel

I have two excel worksheets and I am looking to pull data from one worksheet column based on another column in the same worksheet that contains a unique identifier (name).

I am planning to create two cells in worksheet one that would allow the unique identifier to be entered in one cell (ex. name), and it would pull the data from the other column (time) to display in the other cell.

**Worksheet 1**                               **Worksheet 2**
Name Cell 1:                                    Name Column, Time Column
Time Cell 2: (displayed after entering name)

Is there an excel function or sql function to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a vlookup function already?
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/vlookup.html